# How to retrieve the value from Select html element using JS prototype in php?

Tags: php, javascript, prototypejs

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="prototype.js"></script>
    <script>
    function reload(form){
    var val = $("seltab");alert(val);
    }</script>
echo "<form method = post name = f1 action = '' >";
    echo "<select id = seltab onchange =  'reload(this.form)'>";
        $querysel = "SELECT title_id,author FROM authors NATURAL JOIN books";
    $result1 = mysql_query($querysel) ;
    while($rowID = mysql_fetch_assoc($result1))
    {
        $TitleID = $rowID['title_id'];
        $author = $rowID['author'];
        print "<option value =$TitleID>$author\n";
        print "</option>";
    }
    print "</select>";
```

Comment: =_= Is this PHP? Javascript? PHP in Javascript? It looks like neither really. Please clarify your question.

Comment: I don't see why this is tagged PHP, but I won't retag it again. Instead voting to close because it's not a real question. The OP might want to clearify what he is trying to achieve. Proper source code formatting would be helpful too.

Comment: i have been trying to get the value from dropdown list using JS prototype in php.i have first bound dropdown with database and now i wanted to select one of it and databse according to it should be shown

Comment: Just to clarify: You can't use "JS Prototype **in** PHP". JS has nothing to do with PHP and doesn't care about it. Make sure your problem does not stem from the fact that you don't know about the difference between server-side and client-side languages.

Comment: @user309381 You are aware that unless you are using a ServerSide Javascript engine, all your JavaScript is evaluated and executed on the client-side, are you? Like @deceze said, you cannot use JS in PHP. That's two completely separate interpreters.

Comment: i am beginner but what i am doing is i have bound the database value into dropdown and now i wanted to do like if i choose one of the dropdown option according to it i want to retrieve the database value...please help me how to do it

Comment: function reload(form)
  { var val = $('seltab').getValue();
   self.location = db_test.php?$a=+val;
   alert(val);
   
   
  }

Comment: Start by learning about AJAX, it appears that's what you need.

Answer (score 8):

I think what he means is only the small javascript part of getting the value from the select box in his reload function:

```
$("seltab").getValue();
```

seems the API says there's even a short for that: (http://api.prototypejs.org/dom/form/element/getvalue/)

```
$F("seltab")
```

Comment: i am using javascript(JS prototype) in php. i have bond the database value into dropdown and now i select one of option in the dropdown and database according to it should be shown?

Answer (score 0):

You need to look up the text that matches the returned value:

```
    function getSelectedOption(sel) {
    var opt;
    for ( var i = 0, len = sel.options.length; i < len; i++ ) {
        opt = sel.options[i];
        if ( opt.selected === true ) {
            break;
        }
    }
    return opt;
    }

    // get selected option in seltab
    var opt = getSelectedOption($('seltab'));
    // opt.text is the text
    // opt.value is the value
```

This assumes that "seltab" is the id of your select, not just the name of it.